# Contar el número de columnas con números diferentes

Tags: java, matrices

Es necesario contar el número de columnas en las cuales todos los números son diferentes.

Por ejemplo:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practica {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
        int rows = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the number of columns: ");
        int columns = sc.nextInt();

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[][] mas = new int[rows][columns];
        System.out.println("\nMatrix:");

        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
                mas[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(50) + 1;
                System.out.print(mas[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        int count = 0;
        boolean sinRep = true;
        String nCol = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
            nCol = "";
            sinRep = true;
            for (int i = 0; (i < mas.length) && (sinRep == true); i++) {
                if (nCol.contains(Integer.toString(mas[i][j]))) {
                    sinRep = false;
                }
                nCol += mas[i][j] + "/";
            }
            if (sinRep == true) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Quantity of columns with diferents numbers: " + count);
     }

}
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of rows: 5
Enter the number of columns: 5

Matrix:
38  4   37  39  38  
50  49  15  43  37  
38  22  14  12  38  
19  50  24  32  49  
42  43  39  23  22
```

En este caso se contaría las columnas 2,3,4, la respuesta sería 3 columnas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una idea que se me ocurre es que tengas una variable booleana que esté por defecto a `true`. Es decir, das por supuesto de que en la columna no hay valores repetidos. Por tanto, si se encuentra un valor repetido, que salga del bucle y pase a comprobar la columna siguiente.

Después, haría los bucles a la inversa, para comprobar para cada columna cada una de las filas.

Por último, haría un contador para almacenar el número de columnas en las que no hay ningún valor repetido y añadiría a un `String` los números que ya han salido para dicha columna. Una vez hecho esto, haría la comprobación con la función **[`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))** para saber si el nuevo número que vamos a comparar se encuentra ya en la cadena.

He puesto un separador entre número y número (`/`) dentro del `String` para que no se solapen los números.

Traducido a código sería:

```
boolean sinRepetir = true;
String numerosColumna = "";
int columnasSinRepetir = 0;
String numeroString = "";

for(int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++){
   numerosColumna = "";
   sinRepetir = true;

   for(int i = 0; (i < mas.length) && (sinRepetir == true); i++){
      if(mas[i][j] < 10){
          numeroString = "0" + Integer.toString(mas[i][j]);
      }else{
          numeroString = Integer.toString(mas[i][j]);
      }

      if(numerosColumna.contains(numeroString)){
          sinRepetir = false;
      }
      numerosColumna += mas[i][j] + "/";
   }

   if(sinRepetir == true){
      columnasSinRepetir++;
   }
}

System.out.println("Hay " + columnasSinRepetir + " columnas sin repetir.");
```

Comment: Gracias el codigo trabaja bien, solo tengo una inquientud en la respuesta siempre sale uno menos, es decir si hay 4 columnas con numeros sin repetir  la respuesta sale 3

Comment: @Neon Ya me he dado cuenta del error. Si aparecen números de una sola cifra entonces es posible que lo contengan los números de dos cifras también y entonces lo marca como duplicado aunque no lo sean. He añadido un cero delante para que los números menores de 10 ya no coincidan con cada una de las cifras de los números de dos cifras.

Answer (score 2):

Define dos variables(por ejemplo: int cont=0; boolean found;).

```
for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
    found=false;
    for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
        mas[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(50) + 1;

        for(int k = 0; k < j; k++){
            if(!found && mas[i][j]==mas[i][k]){
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(found){
            cont++;
        }

        System.out.print(mas[i][j] + "\t");
    }

    System.out.println("");
}

System.out.println("Nº columnas con todos sus números diferentes: "+cont);
```